# extended Walker_Page doesn’t output custom start_lvl() or end_lvl()

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom `Walker_Page` class that I have extended like this:

```php
class List_Nav extends Walker_Page {
  function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class='ListNav'>\n";
  }

  function start_el(&$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_page = 0) {
    $output .= '<li class="ListNav-item">';
    $output .= '<a class="ListNav-link" href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ) . '</a>';
    $output .= '</li>';
  }

  function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent</ul>\n";
  }
}
```

But I’m not getting any output from the `start_lvl` or `end_lvl` functions. Is there something I’m missing here or that I need to return? I’m getting the `<li>` output from `start_el()`.

---

**Update with usage**

Here’s how I’m using the walker:

```
if ($post->post_parent) {
  $ancestors=get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
  $root = count($ancestors) - 1;
  $top_parent = $ancestors[$root];
} else {
  $top_parent = $post->ID;
}

$page_list_args = array(
  'child_of'     => $top_parent,
  'depth'        => 0,
  'title_li'     => false,
  'walker'       => new List_Nav
);

wp_list_pages($page_list_args);
```

Comment: You are not returning output variable! isn't it?

Comment: Tell us how you use this class, so we can reproduce your case?

Comment: @Thamizhan Nothing.. And I’m not getting anything trying to `var_dump`, `echo`, `return` or even `die()`.

Comment: start lvl/ end lvl for some reason is not called on the first level (dont ask me why but its not), if you have a child level it is called.

Comment: Wow @David you’re right! Feel free to add this as the answer. I guess it’s the only answer for now. I’ll do something more custom to solve this problem. Thanks! I’ll report this as a bug because the WordPress documentation says nothing of this.

Comment: sure leave it open it would be interesting to see if anyone has an insight into it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `start_lvl()` and `end_lvl()` is always called within the loop and never on a first level. This goes for all WordPress `Walkers` like `Walker_Nav_Menu`, `Walker_Page` and `Walker_Category`.

It’s not super clear but you could guess it when you look at the [Core Walker code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-includes/class-walker-page.php#L43) or when you read the [Walker documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker#Abstract_Methods) about `start_lvl()`.

But in the documentation for [Walker::start_lvl](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker/start_lvl/) it just says that it...

> *Starts the list before the elements are added.*

So perhaps what should be done is an update in the docs.